# IntelliJ, can't start simple web application: Unable to ping server at localhost:4848

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, web-applications, glassfish

I'm trying to open my web app in IntelliJ, which I have opened many times before and it was working perfectly. But today I cannot even start my Tomcat server. It says that address localhost:4848 is already used or cannot be pinged. I was checking used ports using netstat -ano and killing the process that was using this port but it didn't helped. I was also trying different version of Java SDK (8 and 13) and trying to run IntelliJ as administrator but it didn't help too. I'm using GlasFish 5.193.1 and Tomcat 9.0.29

```
[2020-01-22 08:57:11,460] Artifact pas-task-1-mvc:war: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Detected server admin port: 4848
Detected server http port: 8181
Attempting to start domain1.... Please look at the server log for more details.....
```

```
[2020-01-22T20:49:22.639+0100] [Payara 5.193] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1579722562639] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Failed to start, exiting]]

[2020-01-22T20:49:22.640+0100] [Payara 5.193] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1579722562640] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception in thread "main" ]]

[2020-01-22T20:49:22.642+0100] [Payara 5.193] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1579722562642] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMain.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishException: Server failed to start
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.start(AppServerStartup.java:225)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishImpl.start(GlassFishImpl.java:83)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishDecorator.start(GlassFishDecorator.java:63)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl.start(EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl.java:75)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishDecorator.start(GlassFishDecorator.java:63)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishImpl.start(OSGiGlassFishImpl.java:71)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(GlassFishMain.java:130)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishException: Server failed to start
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.doStart(AppServerStartup.java:237)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.start(AppServerStartup.java:223)
    ... 12 more
]]
```

```
Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop, reason: com.intellij.javaee.process.common.WrappedException: java.io.IOException: com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteFailureException: V3 cannot process this command at this time, please wai
```

Comment: What's the error you get with Tomcat? Try `netsh winsock reset` in the Administrator console and reboot.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Unfortunately this command didn't helped. I don't have any logs from Tomcat

Comment: Try the clean server installation with the default settings.

Comment: @Dampsy It sometimes helps me to delete `target` folder and rerun the app. That  creates target folder again and runs app as expected. target folder should be present along side your project folders unless settings are changed

Comment: Neither of your ideas didn't helped

Comment: Did you reboot?

Comment: Yes @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen

Comment: I have another question: how to recreate or create new domain, maybe this will help?

Comment: Alright, I solved my problem. The port for http-listener-1" in domain.xml has bad value. When I set it to 8080 the problem dissaperad.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your project under sdk version 1.8.
Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S -> Project Setting -> Project -> select Project SDK